Overcharges on late checkout
I am concerned about extra charges for my stay at Chequers Lodge in Dalton-in-Furness.
When I booked the hotel, there were no details on check out. Later, they texted me saying check out is at 10:00 am but did not mention any late check out charges. Then, at 10:50, they messaged me saying they would charge 20 pounds extra because I checked out late.
There was no reception in the hotel and nobody was at the hotel; only a person had messaged me. Is it even fair? Please help me on this matter.

Did you leave the premises before 10 AM?

Not sure what your question is. If you did not check out before 10am, as was the communicated requirement, it is reasonable that there were consequences. Whether a 10am checkout is reasonable is another matter, and no stated checkout time at the time of booking seems problematic.

Why would they charge 20 pounds in  Dallas? You mean Dollars?

@BernhardDöbler the location is Dalton-in-Furness, not Dallas in Furus.

How did you book?

I’ve never made a hotel booking where checkout time wasn’t stated somewhere in the confirmation.

@Traveller: but it's often well hidden, especially if the check out time i unusually early.

@Hilmar I wouldn't consider 10AM unusually early though.

@MastaBaba The weird thing is that I just searched for the hotel in question.  On Booking.com and Hotels.com I easily found the checkin and checkout times.  But on what is supposedly the "official" website (www.chequerslodge.co.uk), I couldn't find these times anywhere.  However, I didn't make a booking, so I don't know if anything would be in that fine print.

@PeterM on the official site it’s at least in the T&Cs, but nobody ever reads those. Didn’t go through the whole process either, and definitely didn’t get any confirmation email. But knowing where OP booked would help a lot.

@jcaron I couldn't even find the T&Cs on the official site

@jcaron I found it the T&C.  It's not on the main site.  You only see them when you attempt to book a room, which takes you to a direct-book.com page for the hotel.  The link to the checkout policies is here but there is no mention of a late check out penalty.

In case of any doubts, ask the venue before booking (or in the free cancellation period). I find often "lack of information" is not an error, but a way to hide something, so do not assume default customs. -- On reception desk/lift(elevators)/room door there should be the checkout times. And sometime when you advice early, they can make exception (usually when one less needs)

Fair: as you wrote, it seems a cheap hotel and with a lot automation (and standardized procedures), so the hotels which are not flexible (but they keep cheap prices because of that: cleaning personal is paid just for cleaning, without going forth and back and not extra time at end. An hotel of the Stelios' empire?

If I am staying in a hotel I find out the check-out time: every hotel has one, and it's typically in the range 10am-12pm. Normally it's provided somewhere - not necessarily in the booking email, but in the room or on the website. But even if it's not, you can ask the front desk when you're there, or email/ask on social media before. If you overstay, obviously they charge a penalty because they're not in the business of free accommodation. £20 seems reasonable, since it's intended as a deterrent. If you didn't bother to find the check-out time, and overstayed, expect to pay.

What time did you vacate the room, and put the key (card) into the return box?

Having a checkout deadline, and extra charges in case this deadline is exceeded, is part of how hotels work. They were probably mentioned somewhere in the booking process. In any way, you were aware of the 10am checkout deadline in time.
If the checkout time had been unusually early (eg <9am) or the late checkout fee unusually high (eg more than 50% of the cost of a night for 1h), you'd have a good case that this is unfair and would have needed to be highlighted during booking to become part of the agreement.
However, a 10am checkout time and a £20 late checkout fee seem perfectly reasonable to me. Not having a person at reception only matters if this was the cause of you checking out late.
